# What are the available key types in glib schemas?

Tags: gsettings, glib

In a glib `schema.xml`, keys should have a name and a type, like this:

```
<key name="keyname" type="b">
    <default>true</default>
    <summary>...</summary>
</key>
```

Looking at existing schemas in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, I found booleans (`type="b"`), integer (`"i"`), strings (`"s"`), and doubles (`"d"`).

You may also create pairs, like this:

```
<key name="keyname" type="(ii)">
    <default>(42,24)</default>
    <summary>...</summary>
</key>
```

What are the other possibilities give by glib schemas key types? I couldn't find any documentation about these.

Comment: The [GIO.Settings](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.Settings.html) documentation says they use *"serialized GVariant form"* and that it *"allows any GVariantType for keys"* - so that means anything in [GVariant Type Strings](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.VariantType.html#gvariant-type-strings) ?

Comment: That's it yes !